# How to find strings that are enclosed in quotes and contain specific substring

Tags: regex

I need to have a regex that finds strings in quotes and they also need to contain specific substring. For example the substring could be "joe".

```
"123joe456" -> true
123joe456 -> false
"joe" -> true
"1joe" -> true
"joe2" -> true
"jo2e" -> false
```

Help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work -

```
^\".*?joe.*?\"$
```

Demo [here](http://regex101.com/r/fV2rB8)

Comment: This would also match `blabla"blajoebla"blabla` which might not be wanted.

Comment: start and ending flag needed

Comment: This answer catches cases like " joe" or " something joe " which I also need so I am selecting it as the "accepted answer". However in my case I had to use something different eventually. I used .*\".*joe.*\".* I used this regular expression to search for files where similar occurrences exist and Eclipse didn't play nice with any of the proposed solutions.

Answer (score 2):

like this

```
^\"\w*(?=joe)\w*\"$
```

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/jA9hC5

Answer (score -1):

This:

```
\".*(?<![a-z])(joe)(?![a-z]).*\"
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/rV1gK0).

Will not match `joe` in `"heyiamjoe"`

Or if you don't want that, simply use `^\".*joe.*\"$`

Comment: word boundaries are used only at word endings on both sides. like joe not with 12joe23

Comment: @Gaurav and why it should not match `joe` in `"heyiamjoe"`

Comment: @aelor I just gave the OP an option, if he didn't want in case. There is no harm in giving an option. Is there?